# How to add data from database and jform to jtable perfectly?

Tags: java, database, swing

I had tried to fetch data from database and set it into the jtable but does not set their expected. I tried to fetch the required rows from database and set all those rows into jtable. when I use tbm.setRowCount(0); Only one last row in database table is displayed there and when I do not use this statement, I am able to set all my required row but they set there under the existing rows I am unable to erase the previous rows.

I use this code on my button

```
` try {
            
            
            String DataBaseURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://posproject1.accdb";
            Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(DataBaseURL);
            System.out.println("Successfully connected to data base");

Statement st= connection.createStatement();
            
            String sql1="SELECT * FROM Staff";
            ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery(sql1);
           
DefaultTableModel tbm =(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
            while(rs.next()){
               
          tbm.setRowCount(0);
           tbm.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString(8), rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7)});
            
            }
             
            connection.close();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AddNewStaff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }`
```

[This is the image when I add a new record and click add button that contain the above code with setRowCount(0);  It only displays the last row of my database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCkyD.png)

[Here is the Image when I did not use setRowCount(0); It display all my required rows but the first two rows are the rows that are here before the click because of I had added this same code in default custom code of table so when ever I open this window it display all the existing record by using same code without setRowCount(0); but when I tried to add new record it display the required record but under the existing record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkSWa.png)

I tried to set my required record in jtable starting to set from first row and remove the existing record.
But I don't know how to start setting from first row and how to erase all the previous displayed records from jtable.

Comment: What is the point of setting the row count to 0 in the while loop. This will add a row and then reset the rows to 0, so you can only ever have 1 row. Get rid of the setRowCount(..) statement. If you need to reload the data, then the setRowCount() statement should be executed BEFORE the while loop.

Comment: thanks but can you please tell me how to remove existing rows and add new one

Comment: I just did. Did you read the last sentence?